# Area Enclosed by the Convex Hull of a Set of Random Points

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity, random-graphs, pr.probability

Consider $n$ points generated randomly and uniformly on a unit square. What is the expected value of the area (as a function of $n$) enclosed by the convex hull of the set of points?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update:** By a result of Buchta (Zufallspolygone in konvexen Vielecken, Crelle, 1984; available on digizeitschriften.de) there is a general formula for this expected value,  it is 
$$1 -\frac{8}{3(n+1)} \bigl( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} (1 - \frac{1}{2^k}) - \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}} \bigr) $$
yielding (starting with $n=3$): $11/144$, $11/72$, $79/360$, $199/720$, and so on.

The paper contains in fact a more general result, where the problem is solved for any convex $m$-gon; not just the square.

For asymtotics see other answer(s).

--

Old version (highly incomplete and wrong guess)

For $n=3$ the expected value is $11/144$ and for $n=4$ it is $11/72$.

This information is taken from a [somewhat recent paper (2004) by Johan Philip](http://www.math.kth.se/~johanph/area12.pdf) where the respective distribution functions are studied in detail. I did not see any mention of exact values for other small values of $n$ there (the asymptocic result given already is mentioned though), so they might be unknown.

Comment: Some additional information not directly related: the analog result for 4 points in a cube is rather recent (Zinani; 2003) where the solution is 3977/216000 - pi^2 / 2160 . So, I really guess explicit values for most n could well be unknown.  

Comment: Do you know if in the $2$-dimensional case the expected values continue to be rational?  If so, is there any easy way to see it?

Comment: @Daniel Litt: thanks for the question; turns out my guess was wrong. The edit  to appear soon, should clarify things.  

Comment: @quid:  Thanks!  That does indeed clarify things :).

Answer (score 13):

Let $A$ be the expected area.  Then:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\ln n} (1 - A) = \frac{8}{3} \;.$$
This can be found in many places, e.g., [this MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquarePointPicking.html).

[*Updated with comparisons between the above formula*
(Asymp) *and the exact formula* (Exact) *found by* **quid**.]
$$
\begin{array}{lcccc}
n & & \mathrm{Asymp} & &\mathrm{Exact} \\
n=10 & : & A = 0.39 & : & 0.44 \\
n=100 & : & A = 0.89 & : & 0.88 \\
n=1000 & : & A = 0.98 & : & 0.98
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks, it's a start. Can we say anything about relatively small values of $n$ (i.e. not in the limit behavior)?

Answer (score 12):

For any convex set $K$ in dimension $d$ with volume $V(K)$, it is aymptotically $$V(K)-\frac{T(K)}{(d+1)^{d-1}(d-1)!}n^{-1}ln(n)^{d-1}+O(n^{-1}ln(n)^{d-2}ln(ln(n)))$$ (see {New perspectives in stochastic geometry} by W. Kendall and I. Molchanov, p. 49) where $T(K)$ is the number of "flags", i.e. of sequences $f_0\subset f_1 \subset ... \subset f_{d-1}$ where $f_i$ is an $i$-dimensional facet. There is an abundant literature for random convex hulls and if you're interested there might be an exact closed formula for the square.

Comment: Is there perhaps a factor of V(K) missing from the second term? Compare the formula for $E_{n}(V)$ on p. 2 of this:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02574691