# Probability of landing inside the convex hull of previously sampled points

Tags: pr.probability, convex-polytopes, geometric-probability

Let $\{X_i\}_{0\leq i\leq\infty}$ be i.i.d. random vectors in $\mathbb{R^d}$.
I would like to show that the probability of one point being in the convex hull of the others goes to one with the number of points:
$$\tag{1}\label{claim}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_0\in\mathrm{Conv}(X_1, \ldots, X_n)) = 1,
$$
where the probability is taken with respect to the realization of $(X_0, \ldots, X_n)$.

While this seems intuitive, the following is a counterexample: in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if the $X_i$ are uniformly sampled from the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$, every sampled point almost surely creates a new vertex of the convex hull, and therefore $\mathbb{P}(X_0\in\mathrm{Conv}(X_1, \ldots, X_n)) = 0$.

If the $(X_i)$ are sampled from a continuous distribution, is my initial claim $\eqref{claim}$ true?

Comment: In your counterexample the distribution is not discrete. What do you mean by "continuous" distribution?

Comment: This question is somewhat relevant, as it shows that it is indeed the case for a square. I suppose that's intuitively clear but there are also some quantitative estimates that might be helpful more generally. The probability that the n+1-st point is contained in the convex hull should be 1 minus the expected value of the area of the n-th convex hull (for unit area regions) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93099/area-enclosed-by-the-convex-hull-of-a-set-of-random-points

Comment: Hello, I meant absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, i.e. having a density.

Comment: Thank you @Gabe K, I found some related results for uniform or normal distributions, and your link indeed seems to show it for a uniform distribution on a square; I was however curious about more general results for arbitrary continuous distributions

Comment: Yes, if the distribution has density, you are fine. The reason is pretty straightforward: with probability $1$, the probability that a fixed $X_0$ is in the convex hull of $X_{m+1},\dots,X_{m+d+1}$ is positive for every $m$ (if $f$ is the density, that is true for every Lebesgue point of $f$, say). Thus, the probability $p(X_0,n)$ that $X_0$ is not in the convex hull of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ goes to $0$ and the dominated convergence theorem finishes the story. The interesting question is the speed of convergence, but then we need some restrictions on the density to make it meaningful.

Comment: Thank you @fedja, that seems exactly the reasoning I am looking for.
• Would you mind detailing the argument that the probability of $X_0$ being in a convex hull of size d is non-zero for a Lebesgue point of the density? I suppose $X_0$ is taken on the support of the density?
• The dominated convergence is necessary to go from a fixed $X_0$ to a random $X_0$, is that right?

Comment: Alright, I do understand the second point regarding the dominated convergence. I am still trying to formalise the first one, i.e. that if $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the density $f(x_0) > 0$, almost surely the probability of $x_0$ being in the convex hull of $d+1$ points is non-zero. I have tried reasoning on the probability measure of local balls around $x_0$ to exploit the property of Lebesgue points...

Comment: Trying to explain 1st part of @fedja 's idea. Suppose $x_0$ is a Lebesgue point such that $f(x_0)>0$ (the probability of these points is 1). Let $B_{r}$ be the ball of radius $r$ around $x_0$. Let $1>q>0$. Since $x_0$ is a Lebesgue point, for $r$ small enough, the Lebesgue measure of any set of the form $B\cap\{x:f(x)>f(x_0)/2\}$,  where $B$ is ball of radius $qr$ contained in $B_r$, is positive. Take $d+1$ points in $R^d$ such that $x_0$ is in the interior of their convex hull. Take small balls a round the $d+1$ points, and shrink this structure as $r\to 0$ until the prob of each ball >0.

Comment: Thank you @RonP, your remark helped me figure it out! @ fedja, feel free to turn into an answer.